# I created clocks and I want to make the background transparent

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, background, clock

I tried to write clock in Java.

Here is example of my code.

1. I want to make the background transparent but I don't know how.
2. I want to place my program on top of all Windows. An example of how that must look :
   [image: example how that must look].

There are two classes in my program. First of the called clock and second is Executor
screen:
[image: screen].

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class clock extends JFrame 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel timeF;
    JPanel panel;
    
    
    public clock()
    {
            super("Java Clock by Anton" );
            setSize (400,90);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(true);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel.setOpaque(false);
            timeF = new JLabel("0:0:0");
            timeF.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,48));
            
            panel.add(timeF);
            add(panel);
            
            Timer t = new Timer(1000,new Listener());
            t.start();
    }       
        
    
    class Listener implements ActionListener
    {
    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    
        {
    
            Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            
            int hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int min = rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int sec = rightNow.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            
            timeF.setText(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. All the JDK classes follow this standard. Learn by example. 2) Swing components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. 3) Use pack() instead of setSize(). You can add an `EmptyBorder` to your `JLabel` to give extra space around the text. 4) there is no need for the panel. You can add the label directly to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Right after you create your JPanel, add the following:

```
setUndecorated(true);
setVisible(true);
// has the alpha parameter set to transparent.
setBackground(new  Color(255,0,0,0));
panel.setOpaque(false);
```

But once the Frame is undecorated, you won't be able to close it, so you may need to add some additional code in your panel.  A `mouseListener` will work.

Create an inner class

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent a) {
         System.exit(-1);
     }
}
```

Then

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
```

When you click on the time, it will exit the program.

Note:  You should not be extending `JFrame`.  It is best to create an instance and use that.  The rule is, prefer `composition over inheritance` when it makes sense to do so.